# Google Merchant Feed: Roboted Content

Tags: google

I'm trying to submit my a merchant feed to Google Shopping Search (aka Froogle) but every now and then I get an email saying that the URLs in the feed are "Roboted Content".

The URLs in the feed are tracking ones which means that they redirect to the real product pages. Both directories aren't in my robots.txt. Yet Google keeps telling me that they are blocked for its crawlers.

How can I find out exactly what the offending URL is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you post a feed to your merchant account in Google Base, it will give you lines where the errors are. Take a look at that.